# Elasticsearch match multiple fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am recently using `elasticsearch` in a website. The scenario is, I have to search a string on a`field`. So, if the `field` is named as `title` then my search query was,

```
"query" :{"match": {"title": my_query_string}}.
```

But now I need to add another `field` in it. Let say, `category`. So i need to find the matches of my string which are in `category` :`some_category` and which have `title` : `my_query_string` I tried with `multi_match`. But it does not give me the result i am looking for. I am looking into `query filter` now. But is there way of adding two fields in such criteria in my `match` query?

Comment: How do you define the category? Is it something that the user will specify or something that will be implied?
eg.
Say you have a bookstore, and the user now browses the "fantasy" category. If he searches you want only to search the titles under this category?

Comment: yes. category is another field like the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
GET indice/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "title"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category": "category"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `should` with `must` if desired.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I think that what you need is something like this:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "title": YOUR_QUERY_STRING,
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "category": YOUR_CATEGORY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your `category` field is analyzed, then you will need to use `match` instead of `term` in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
      "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {"match": {"title": "bold title"},
                            {"match": {"body": "nice body"}}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "category": "xxx"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```